# Python code to extract information from molecular dynamics simulation file

Tags: python, regex

I have an output file from a molecular dynamics simulation. One part of the file is as follows:

```
     Entering Dynamics:    iteration =  3200
                           time      =   0.7740 pico-seconds


     Andersen thermostat:   22 collisions

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)
O             1.2548684197        0.6424461240        0.7655878783    0   0   0
O            13.1348755441        1.7104775362        0.9831193322    0   0   0
Si            0.2961184815        3.9514997961        1.4334508031    0   0   0
Si            3.4858850598        6.3535750817       -0.0759632619    0   0   0
O             4.1551025227        5.0479390695        0.3635581483    0   0   0
Si            7.0355725487        6.6231051760        3.5097262837    0   0   0
O             6.2913557105        5.2296438029        3.7778484627    0   0   0
O             9.8141798579        5.2550557888        0.6738163980    0   0   0
Si            9.4725273964        6.6846863678        1.5204773455    0   0   0
Si            4.8006823796       11.3515927947        1.8133971611    0   0   0
O             5.9975449939        7.8470275094        3.2154093810    0   0   0
O             7.8754782756        9.8763121275        0.5722748194    0   0   0
O            -0.2959658746        0.0533054014        2.8651388320    0   0   0
Si            7.4183110714        1.6011961440        1.4468400910    0   0   0
O             5.0804368525       -0.3344709270        5.3555368062
Si           11.5338967914        1.7892923751        1.3908462020    0   0   0
O            12.0656978779        1.0046462656        4.0351985742
O             0.5207366786        4.4457166923        2.9846728696    0   0   0
Si            5.1841357277        4.0728488582        4.0746941885
O             5.1872386308        3.1106064770        2.7381557077    0   0   0
O             5.8056941280        3.0861498500        5.2873425714
O             8.4040054974        2.9471067707        1.1598483191    0   0   0
O             1.8608924768        6.1316507204        5.0920863017
O             3.7164141756        4.6241968448        4.3720160199
O            10.7430822384        6.8454765622        2.5612287404    0   0   0
Si            1.8961563104        7.4020010486        3.9672729592    0   0   0
O             3.4314681107        7.7675775631        3.6568414736    0   0   0
O             7.8525657574        7.1129666203        4.8139136918
Si            9.2285669588        9.1345382788        1.2296763780    0   0   0
O             8.0175722171        6.4483381802        2.2249489379    0   0   0
Si           -1.5864332607       10.6831540134        3.6182013263    0   0   0
O             4.6458025650        9.9775888757        2.7132759539    0   0   0
Si            4.9655131010       -0.8235046017        3.7462341115    0   0   0
O             8.7806776962       11.8629093332        4.0996484633
Si            9.8620383541       13.0065268916        4.4627978826
O            11.1203784142       11.3989385058        3.0725920949    0   0   0
Si            1.7370720581        0.4985632232        5.4133887769
O             7.8689631579       -0.8411424613        6.8001682976
O             1.8593021975        3.4289762669        5.3588309051
Si            8.2630864331        0.6006636472        6.0640224774
O             7.7797871380        2.0415566369        6.7014630911
O             1.7253534194        5.0053996874        7.1288337168
Si            2.8380624986        4.7709548130        5.7830629234
O             4.8238599095        6.1446392654        8.9217003102
O             6.1138021636        3.8559899537        7.9573682387
Si            5.4316507955        5.2744024202        7.6601085633
O             9.1685324914        4.4050300422        5.4453592810
Si            6.2413164651        2.6077699732        6.7965931056
Si           10.0301402752        5.4300848786        6.3239657737
O            13.7770558709        4.7605959661        6.6173171924
O             1.2583474444        8.5881843912        4.8423762424
Si            3.7672356322        7.4407292523        9.0018747173
O             4.4866104836        8.5787761710        7.9957768354
Si            7.7655911405        7.1471163307        6.4241215090
O             6.6577840429        6.1141075159        7.0251280749
O             9.3451435563        6.7756485511        6.9331690833
O            12.2125407892        9.8457335674        6.5913932616
Si            4.2384301635        9.6692959125        6.7673324052
O             5.0544710564       10.9211013065        7.3404829696
O             9.6907487259       10.2861855536        6.1779769547
C             3.7233324270        7.7989590137       10.8768331090
H             3.0282047684        7.0416044129       11.2795989504
H             4.6979392526        7.5564111614       11.2953932171
H             3.3833398135        8.7948495362       11.2347725215


     kinetic energy (Ekin) =           0.09821287 Ry
     temperature           =         279.39795411 K 
     Ekin + Etot (const)   =       -2637.60538954 Ry

     Writing config-only to output data dir ./SiO2.save/
```

It gives atomic positions like this for every iteration. I want to calculate the bond length that is the distance between highest z coordinate of the Si atom and the z coordinate of the C atom from the set of coordinates. The bond length should be calculated for every set of coordinates in the file and stored as an array or list. How to do it using a python script? I have tried a lot of methods but none of them giving me correct answer.

I tried this

```
import re

# Regular expression pattern to extract the Si atomic positions
pattern = r"Si\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)"

# List to store the highest z coordinate of Si atoms for each iteration
highest_z_coords = []

# Open the file containing the atomic positions and iterate over its lines
with open("cf3.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Check if the line contains the iteration number and atomic positions
        if "ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)\n" in line:
            # Initialize the highest z coordinate to a negative value
            highest_z = -float("inf")
            # Iterate over the next few lines to extract the atomic positions of Si atoms
            for i in range(6):
                next_line = next(f)
                # Use regular expression to extract the Si atomic positions
                match = re.search(pattern, next_line)
                if match:
                    # Extract the z coordinate of the Si atom and update the highest z coordinate
                    z_coord = float(match.group(3))
                    if z_coord > highest_z:
                        highest_z = z_coord
            # Add the highest z coordinate to the list for this iteration
            highest_z_coords.append(highest_z)

# Print the list of highest z coordinates for each iteration
print(highest_z_coords)
```

but it gives error.

Comment: What should be the expected result of your sample?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have a main loop doing a line by line read of the file.
Each line is checked for the text

```
"ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)\n"
```

When this text is found you then cycle a range of the next 6 lines getting the `z coord` from your `Si` lines.
The highest value in the 6 lines is set to the variable `highest_z` which is then appended to the list `highest_z_coords` at the end of this loop of 6.

Then your code jumps back to the main loop and carries on reading the lines in the file from next line after the 6 just processed, and again it's looking for a line with the text `"ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)\n"` 
In your example data there is only one line that contains `"ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)\n"` which has already been read. This means the loop now just iterates through the rest of the lines in the file doing nothing more.
`highest_z_coords` gets no more appends and therefore it holds and prints just the one value from the first 6 lines after `"ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)\n"`

If you are wanting to get the highest z for each group of 6 in the 64 elements you could include a while loop that basically checks for the next empty line after you start processing the segments of 6. Or you could set it to end when the Carbon element is found etc.

I have modified your code to loop through all the elements (64) and processing as a batch of 6 thus producing 10 `highest_z values` in the `highest_z_coords` list.

Example Code

```
import re

# Regular expression pattern to extract the Si atomic positions
pattern = r"Si\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(-?\d+\.\d+)"

# List to store the highest z coordinate of Si atoms for each iteration
highest_z_coords = []

# Open the file containing the atomic positions and iterate over its lines
with open("cf3.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Check if the line contains the iteration number and atomic positions
        if "ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)\n" in line:
            ### Header text for elements found start processing all in the list
            processing_segments = True
            ### While loop continually runs the range of 6 until processing_segments = False
            while processing_segments is True:
                # Initialize the highest z coordinate to a negative value
                highest_z = -float("inf")
                # Iterate over the next few lines to extract the atomic positions of Si atoms
                for i in range(6):
                    next_line = next(f)
                    ### When the next line is empty signifying the line after the last
                    ### element, processing can stop and break from the highest z coord check
                    if next_line == "\n":
                        processing_segments = False  # This will end the while loop
                        break  # This will end the range loop 
                    # Use regular expression to extract the Si atomic positions
                    match = re.search(pattern, next_line)
                    if match:
                        # Extract the z coordinate of the Si atom and update the highest z coordinate
                        z_coord = float(match.group(3))
                        if z_coord > highest_z:
                            highest_z = z_coord

                # Add the highest z coordinate to the list for this iteration
                if highest_z != float('-inf'):
                    highest_z_coords.append(highest_z)

# Print the list of highest z coordinates for each iteration
print(highest_z_coords)
```

I assume your expected output for the list `highest_z_coords` is this;

```
[3.5097262837, 1.8133971611, 1.446840091, 4.0746941885, 3.9672729592, 4.4627978826, 6.0640224774, 7.6601085633, 9.0018747173, 6.7673324052]
```